# Boost.Python: Calling virtual functions from C++

Tags: c++, python, boost

I'm not looking for help on *exposing* virtual functions to Python, I would like to know how I can call the said virtual functions from the C++ side. Consider this...

```
// ====================
// C++ code
// --------------------

struct Base
{
    virtual void func() {
        cout << "Hello from C++!";
    }
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(name)
{
    // Expose the class and its virtual function here
}


// ====================
//   Python code
// --------------------

from name import Base

class Deriv(Base):
    def func():
        print('Hello from Python!')
```

Any advice on how I might grab a `Base*` to the derived type such that when I do `base->func()`, the Python function is called? The Boost docs only describe how to expose the virtual functions to Python, not how to call their redefinitions from C+.

Comment: I'd guess if you expose it, it either just works or is not supported. Have you tried it? (either have another method on the object to call the virtual or have a separate function that will take instance and call the virtual).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach will not work in such a simple way; you have to add wrapper to your python class, from which python class will be subsequently derived. [here, under 1.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6668670/boost-python-wrapping-a-virtual-method/6670470#6670470) I explained briefly how it works. So, to call python-override of a c++ virtual method, use `get_override` and call the returned object with `()`.

For some code, see e.g. [here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~yade-dev/yade/trunk/view/head:/py/pack/_packPredicates.cpp#L31), where `Predicate` and `PredicateWrap` are defined, but then `PredicateWrap` is [really exposed](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~yade-dev/yade/trunk/view/head:/py/pack/_packPredicates.cpp#L345) to python; calling the overridden methods is done [here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~yade-dev/yade/trunk/view/head:/py/pack/_packPredicates.cpp#L56), but that is hidden to the user.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just call `extract<Base*>(obj)` where `obj` is `python::object`.